# Do I need to provide images with different size if I retrieve it using Picasso or Glide or Volley?

Tags: android, android-volley, picasso, android-glide

Usually, it's better if we provide image in different densities (sdpi, mdpi,hdpi, xhdpi, etc). Do I need to provide the same thing if I retrieve it from the server using some kind of library (Picasso, Glide, Volley, etc) or should I just provide the original image and the library will convert it to the appropriate size and density to my app?

**Note:** If I provide images with different size or densities, I don't retrieve all of it. I just retrieve all the images url and just download once of them. Is it better this way, or is it better to provide one original image url and retrieve it and re-size it to the appropriate size?

Answer (score 2):

It`s depends from purposes. For example if you need to show only small profile picture like this:

[image: Item from friends list]

you need to have only small images on your server side, it will reduce memory usage, network usage and time to display picture.

Another situation with large images.
For example:

[image: Album Picture]

Here display music albums and images must have high resolution.

Better if you have two type of image on your server one small and one large, and than you can receive image depend by situation.

Don`t worry about size on hdd this will take ImageLoaders control itself.
Image size impact on memory usage and network usage.

Answer (score 1):

Downloading different sizes is definitely considered good practice. The Google I/O 2014 app [wrote a post on exactly this topic](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/doc/IMAGES.md) last year.

Glide provides the [BaseGlideUrlLoader](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/3.0/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/load/model/stream/BaseGlideUrlLoader.java) class that allows you to bucket your image requests into a variety of different sizes, provided your backend supports it.

For example, Glide's [FlickrModelLoader](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/3.0/samples/flickr/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/samples/flickr/FlickrModelLoader.java) uses Flickr's API along with your request size to download only the smallest image required, saving battery, bandwidth, and ensuring the request completes as quickly as possible.

A simple example implementation of BaseGlideUrlLoader might look like this:

```
public class ExampleUrlLoader extends BaseGlideUrlLoader<YourModel> {
    private static final int ORIGINAL_SIZE = -1;


    @Override
    protected String getUrl(YourModel model, int width, int height) {
       int maxSize = Math.max(width, height);
       final int size;
       if (maxSize > 800) {
           size = ORIGINAL_SIZE;
       } else if (maxSize > 400) {
           size = 800;
       } else if (maxSize > 200) {
           size = 400;
       } else if (maxSize > 50) {
           size = 200;
       } else {
           size = 50;
       }
       return model.getBaseUrl() + "&size=" + size;
    }
}
```

You can also check out Glide's [GiphyModelLoader](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/3.0/samples/giphy/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/samples/giphy/GiphyModelLoader.java) for another example, and/or Glide's [wiki page on bucketing sizes](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Downloading-custom-sizes-with-Glide).

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to have them in several sizes. If you only transfer the image in the size that it will actually be shown, you will lower the amount of data that needs to be transferred from the sever along with taking care of a few OOM errors. If you are worried about the size on the hdd this will take, you can always downscale one original image on the server prior to sending the stream.

Comment: by yes, do you mean it's better to provide all size of the images on the server?

Comment: Yes, it's better, but people tend to avoid it because it means more work to be done! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no certain answer. Those libraries will resize your image with no problems (and OOM errors mentioned in Bojan's post

**BUT**

The whole thing is in image quality. If scaled at runtime it may be worse that pre-scaled. So if you care about how will it look like(and imho you should) then provide different dpi images

Answer (score 0):

I think the only issue is image downloading performance. If you downloading image which is larger then your image view you the image will be resized but you will use more data than needed for smaller image downloading. If you will download smaller image you will use less data but the image quality will be low.